# Rendering table only if has data

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, user-interface, html-table

I have table in one form. after user submits the form data gets displayed in the result table. the problem is table header is getting displayed even before after user submit the form and data comes.

so I created one variable.

```
const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false)
```

I have set the flag as true after API call.

```
  const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/certificates', {
            params: param,
        });
        setFlag(true);  //Here changing the variable value to true.
        setResponse(data);
}
```

and in table component div we are putting this flag

```
   <div id="flag">
```

I also tried in `table` component

```
 <table className="table table-striped table-bordered " id="flag>
```

but none of them working. Could you please suggest on the same.

[image]
My requirement is table should be rendered only if API gets called and it has data.

Comment: did you use the async keyword in your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this in return section

Flag Check:-

```
    return <div>
{flag && 
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>class</th>
    </tr>
    <table> }
</div>
```

data check:-

```
return <div>
{(response?.length > 0) && 
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>class</th>
    </tr>
    <table> }
</div>
```

we are using && (AND Operator) to check if flag is true then it show table otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

```
 let  data  = [];
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/certificates', {
    params: param,
          }).then(response=>{
        data=response.data;
        setFlag(true);  //Here changing the variable value to true.
        setResponse(data);
          }).catch(err => {})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
          const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/certificates', {
                params: param,
            });
//add condition to check the length of data 
if(data.length> 0){
            setFlag(true);  //Here changing the variable value to true.
            setResponse(data);

} else {
 setFlag(false);  
 setResponse(data);
}
    }
```

in JSX use the flag as below

```
{flag?<table className="table table-striped table-bordered " id="flag">:null}
```

Comment: giving error . Flag does not exist on type jsx.IntrinsicElements. I have already declared it on top.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the closing " below is the updated code. I have updated the answer aswell 
 
{flag?<table className="table table-striped table-bordered " id="flag">:null}

Answer (score 1):

Using if statement or conditional render should do it

```
if (data !== null && data.length > 0){
setFlag(true)
}
```

or when you render the content

```
{data ? 
<div id="flag"> </div> : null }
```